# Mathematica association does not work on symbols

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, associations

Question about using an association within `Replace`.

If I have an association which contains symbols like so:

```
dict = <|Subscript[r, 1] -> 1, Subscript[r, 2] -> 2|>
```

and I do some operation using these variables for e.g.

```
lst = f[#1[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{Subscript[r, 1], 1},{Subscript[r, 2],2}}
```

Then, if I try to use the association defined in `dict` within `Replace`, it doesn't seem to recognize the variable.

```
lst /. f[x_, y_] -> dict[x]
```

and throws a `KeyAbsent` error:

```
{Missing["KeyAbsent", Subscript[r, 1]], 
 Missing["KeyAbsent", Subscript[r, 2]]}
```

Here's a minimal working example to reproduce the error:

```
Block[{dict, lst},
dict = <|Subscript[r, 1] -> 1, Subscript[r, 2] -> 2|>;
lst = f[#1[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{Subscript[r, 1], 1},{Subscript[r,2], 2}};
lst /. f[x_, y_] -> dict[x]
]
```

Why is the output not `{1,2}` ?

Comment: Hi @Szabolcs, all good points. I went a bit overboard as a result of my frustrations. I've modified the post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this addresses my concerns. Regarding why I removed the [tag:bugs] tag: we try to add this tag only after a bug was confirmed by the community (see tag description).

Comment: Ah right ! Thanks. Just out of curiosity, how does one go about verifying that a result is a bug ? Is it posted in the chat first ?

Comment: The idea is that if you post a new question, you should not use [tag:bugs]. Most of the time, you should not use it at all for your _own_ questions. Feel free to add this tag to _other people's questions_ if after a careful look, you have become convinced that it really is a bug (and not a misunderstanding by the asker). You can think of it as "volunteer peer review".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. Compare the output of these two lines:

```
lst /. f[x_, y_] -> dict[x]
```

and

```
lst /. f[x_, y_] :> dict[x]
```

In the first case, `dict[x]` evaluates to `Missing["KeyAbsent", x]` and then a value is substituted for `x`.

In the second case, first a value such as `Subscript[r,1]` is substituted for `x` in `dict[x]`, obtaining `dict[ Subscript[r,1] ]`. Evaluation proceeds afterwards.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks. Why is it that after 5 years of consistent MMA use, I still fall for these "trivial" oversight ? I wonder if its just my stupidity or whether this notations is unnatural.

Comment: @v1j4y The output `Missing["KeyAbsent", Subscript[r, 1]]` really is misleading. Consider how we always use `:=` instead of `=` in function definitions, even though _technically_ it is necessary only sometimes. I think it would make sense to default to `:>` in replacement rules as well, unless there is a clear reason to use `->`. For some reason, we don't conventionally do this, as a community. Maybe it's time to change.

Comment: Right ! So the `->` signifies: evaluate then replace and `:>` signifies: replace and hold right ? Similar to the `=` and the hold version `:=`.